# NestJs Subsciber + TypeOrm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

2

I have a subscriber for NestJS to listen to any create, update or delete events (TypeORM). When one of these events is fired, I'd like to use an injected service in order to create a new revision entry.

However, it seems I cannot get the dependency . ***I getting error Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JobInterviewerSubscriber (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the JobPostingModule context***

Keys Files:
Jobs.entity.ts
JobPostingModule.ts

Jobs.entity.ts

```
import { BaseEntity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, Entity, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany, JoinTable, EventSubscriber, EntitySubscriberInterface, InsertEvent, Repository, UpdateEvent, Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { Panelist } from './panelist.entity';
import { JobStatus, JobLocation, JobType, JobPriority } from '../job-posting/enum/job.enum';
import { Agency } from './agency.entity';
import { Candidates } from '../entities/candidates.entity';
import { JobInterviewers } from './job-interviewers.entity';
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectConnection } from '@nestjs/typeorm/dist/common/typeorm.decorators';

@Entity()   
export class Jobs extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({type: 'varchar', length: 100})
    title: string;

    @Column({type: 'enum', enum: JobPriority})
    priority: JobPriority;

  

    @Column({type: 'int2', default: 0})
    roundCount: number;

    @OneToMany(type => JobInterviewers, jobInterviewers => jobInterviewers.jobs, {eager:true})
    jobInterviewers: JobInterviewers[];

    @ManyToMany(type => Agency, agency => agency.jobs)
    @JoinTable({name: 'job_agency_table'})
    agencies: Agency[];
    
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date;
}

@EventSubscriber()
@Injectable()
export class JobInterviewerSubscriber
  implements EntitySubscriberInterface<JobInterviewers> {
 
    constructor(
      @InjectConnection() readonly connection: Connection,
    ) {
      connection.subscribers.push(this);
    }

    listenTo() {
    return JobInterviewers;
    }

    async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<JobInterviewers>) {

    const jobsRepo: Repository<Jobs> = event.connection.manager.getRepository<Jobs>('Jobs');
    const jobInterviewersRepo: Repository<JobInterviewers> = event.connection.manager.getRepository<JobInterviewers>('JobInterviewers');
    jobInterviewersRepo
      .count({
        where: { jobs: { id: event.entity.jobs.id } },
      })
      .then((count: number) => {
        jobsRepo.update({ id: event.entity.jobs.id }, { roundCount: count });
      });
  }
}
```

JobPostingModule.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JobPostingController } from './job-posting.controller';
import { JobPostingService } from './job-posting.service';
import { AuthModule } from '../auth/auth.module';
import { RecruitmentService } from '../recruitment/recruitment.service';
import { JobInterviewerSubscriber } from 'src/entities/job-posting.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule
  ],
  controllers: [JobPostingController],
  providers: [JobPostingService, RecruitmentService,JobInterviewerSubscriber]
})
export class JobPostingModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, there any many different possibilities:

- is the connection loaded globally?
- is the connection properly configured at all? Does it give any errors of connection?
- I see that your module does not import `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Jobs])`. If your TypeORM configuration doesn't load entities automatically, you should load them as imports manually